# Is this just a simplified spelling?

Tags: notation

I am currently reading a book and saw a formula that contained the equation labeled Pic $1$ in this  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GafI1.png).

What is this kind of equation called or is it simply another way of displaying Pic $2$?

Comment: This is not an equation. Please use the terminology correctly. An equation describes an equality using $=$. The pictures show a *column vector* and a *row vector*, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pic1 is a column vector, Pic2 is a row vector

Comment: If so, then why is there a comma in Pic2?